# get the data in combobox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I would like to ask if how to get the data in a select(box) not the value one...example: if i select (one) i would like to get the data "one" instead of (1) and transfer it to another inputs..how do i do that?

```
<select name="number">
<option value="1">one</option>
<option value="2">two</option>
</select>
```

if i do this:

```
$num = $_POST['number'];
```

the value of $num will be (1) how do i make it (one)?

Answer (score 0):

Only the value attribute of a select option gets passed to the php script. So you'd need to update your option value to `<option value="one">one</option>`